# Coturn does not perform username& password authentication

Tags: turn, coturn

I have configured the coturn servers with long term cred (basic authen) in aws autoscaling group and placed it behind an AWS NLB.

Below is my coturn configuration in turnserver.conf

```html
listening-port=3478
external-ip=$MY_AWS_NLB_ENDPOINT
min-port=32355
max-port=65535
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech
user=$MY_USERNAME:$MY_PASSWORD
stale-nonce

no-stdout-log
syslog
no-multicast-peers

no-cli

no-tlsv1
no-tlsv1_1
#no-tlsv1_2
```

However, when I placed it behind the NLB, the app connects to the NLB and works just fine, except there is no authentication part, even if I configure wrong username password in my app.
What is wrong with my coturn config?
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Is coturn receiving the Allocate request? Do you have a network trace that shows the messages exchanged between the client and the server? (Just the summary of packets shown by Wireshark would do)